# How to list attributes for all SKUs in the system? My code only shows half products

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute, product-collection

I am running code below to list out custom options for each product in the system.  If I run code below as is I get about half SKUs in the system. However, if I comment out the line between "fetch...end fetch" then I get a list of products (of course without custom store attribute.)

I need custom options for the entire product list. We are running Magento 1.4.

```
<?php
    require_once('../app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    set_time_limit(0);
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productCollection = $productModel->getCollection();
    $count = 1;

    foreach($productCollection as $_product) 
    {
        //fetch & display attributes
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
        $custom_option_store_array = $product->getAttributeText('custom_option_store');

        if (is_array($custom_option_store_array)) {
            $custom_option_store = implode(',',$custom_option_store_array);
        } else {
            $custom_option_store = $custom_option_store_array;
        }

        echo $count.' Sku '.$_product->getSku().' custom_option_store : '.$custom_option_store;
        echo "<br>";
        // end fetch and display.
        echo $count.' Sku '.$_product->getSku();
        echo "<br>";
        $count++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'half SKUs in the system'? any log or exception?

Comment: Yes, sounds like an error to me.  Check the latest file in <magento root>/var/report and see the latest timestamp on file (ls -la would work in unix).  See if the time is the same as when you ran into this sku issue.